# Use SASS instead of LESS in new Laravel 5 project

Tags: laravel, sass, less, gulp, laravel-elixir

How can I use SASS instead of LESS in a new Laravel 5 installation?

A couple of weeks ago SASS was the chosen pre-processor but since then, Taylor has changed Laravel to use LESS out the box. Laravel Elixir / Gulp still has support for compiling SASS but I am not sure how to get the SASS files into my project in the first place.

If anyone has any ideas of the steps, please holla.

Comment: Whoever downvoted please explain why you think it is too broad? It is actually very specific if you read the question. It is a valid programming question about a framework that has fairly strict instructions on how to set things up with regards to the use of Laravel-Elixir and the SASS port of Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More example [how to](https://github.com/laravel/elixir)

```
elixir(function(mix) {
   mix.sass("app.scss");
});
```

By default, larvel 5 store all assets in vendor/bower_components

And if you want use for example angular.js, which stored in 
`vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js`

You publish them to your public folder.

```
 elixir(function(mix) {
       mix.sass("app.scss").
                publish('angular/angular.js', 'public/js/angular/angular.js';
 });
```

I think, the same logic will work and for sass files.

Or, you can try, [via](https://laravel-news.com/2014/10/setting-laravel-elixr-bootstrap/)

```
var paths = {
    'bootstrap': './vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/'
}

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass("style.scss", 'public/css/', {includePaths: [paths.bootstrap + 'stylesheets/']})
});
```

Comment: My question is not how to compile them, but how to get the SASS files into the resources directory in the first place. Are they just copied in from a download or are they part of a dependancy like they have been in the past using Bower?

Comment: I have followed those instructions but I am getting an error of `Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?`

Comment: It's ok, I ran `npm rebuild node-sass` and it worked I think.

Comment: If you're compiling bootstrap-sass with the SASS version that comes with Elixir, you have to add `elixir.config.css.sass.pluginOptions.precision = 10;` to your gulpfile.js after your "var exliir" is defined.  Otherwise the default precision of 5 causes alignment issues with input-group and other Bootstrap elements.